# How can input change between normal text type and checkbox in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, input, checkbox, formhelper

In one of my friend's cakephp project,her colleague wrote a checkbox like this :

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BKt5D1lCAAA1ZfJ.jpg

And he created it in this way:

```
echo $this->Form->input('accept_twins', array('label' => 'Accept twins?'));
```

How could it be!?!!!

If I change anything in the `fieldname param 'accept_twins'`,or copy it to other `ctp` file,it comes to this:

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BKuAunRCEAAVAWs.jpg

How could it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Whether there are such rules?

Actually，I know how to create a nomarl checkbox,I just can't understand how could this happen?Does anyone know it?

妈蛋！累感不爱！蠢哭了！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formhelper guesses the input type to use based on db field type. If it shows checkbox it means the field `accept_twins` is of type TINYINT(1) in the table for that particular model. If you change the field name it will change the input type based on type of that field in db or show input type text by default if the field isn't in db.

Comment: It seems so，but why it become input type text when I copy it from `add.ctp` into `search.ctp`.Does it query from db before `insert` and do not before `select`?

Comment: There is no db querying before insert or select. The model schema is fetch (and cached) when model instance is created. Depending on where your `search.ctp` is placed and which controller action you are calling the form helper is unable to guess the model hence you get the text type input. Specify the model name as first param of Form->create() call in the `search.ctp` and you should get a checkbox for that field.

Comment: I hope you are also reading the CakePHP manual and not just randomly tinkering with an existing cake app :)

Comment: TAT I have find in the CakePHP api and cakebook,but can't find how to explian this situation.And I feel so so so bad about this.I know how to do,just in a bad mood._(:3」∠)_